# Using 3DS Max's Python API, How to Select All Objects in Scene?

Tags: python, 3dsmax, 3ds

I'm struggling to understand how to *select* objects using the MaxPlus class approach.

For example, the following script will print the material used for every `INode` objects in the `NodeTree` (assuming I *manually* select them in the 3DS Max Viewport)

```
nodes = MaxPlus.SelectionManager.GetNodes()
for n in nodes:
    print(n.Material)
```

The trouble is, I don't know how to get those objects from a script-only perspective as opposed to manually selecting them.

I've found the `MaxPlus.SelectionManager` class but it seems it requires an existing selection to be made.

Basically, I'm just trying to issue a command equivalent of pressing `CTRL + A` in the 3DS Max viewport to select all scene objects.

Using 3DS Max 2016 + PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

MaxPlus.Core.GetRootNode().Children